# How can I make sure all of the filters have registered themselves in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dynamic list. It has a state called `filters`:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([])
```

This list is encapsulated in a context called `ListContext` and it exposes a method called `registerFilter`.

A developer can add any number of filters to my list using that `registerFilter`.

Each filter uses that `registerFilter` to register itself.

Now, this is where I'm stuck. I want to do something only when all of the filters are registered. How can I do that?

For example, let's say a developer wants to add two filters to my list. These filters are for title, name, and age.

I can use an effect to react to `filters` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // I know filters are changed, but how can I know that it's the end of them?
    someMethodToBeRunOnlyWhenAllFiltersAreAdded() // this is now called 3 times for title, name, and age
}, [filters])
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here, is just to use in build-in useMemo:

```
const filteredItems = useMemo(() => someMethodToBeRunOnlyWhenAllFiltersAreAdded(filters), [filters]);
```

Assuming the filters array is an state in that context holding component. In newer react versions (18+), state updates are automatically batched and the function executing the filters will only be called once, when the filters are updated in sync.

https://beta.reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#automatic-batching

Also be aware that in StrictMode react renders all useEffects & useMemo etc. twice during mount during development to surface un/re-mount bugs earlier.

Comment: I tried it. The batch section worked. But I faced a new problem. Simply put a `console.log(filterables)` inside the `useMemo` and you'll see that it's logged twice. Once as `[]` and once as `['Title', 'Name', 'Age']`. This means my function would be run twice. Also this means that if there are no filterables, I won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: In most cases, it should not matter how often things run, what matters is that the results are correct and that cleanups and aborts are done correctly and no stale data is used.